# unexpected behavior in pmatch while matching '+' in R

Tags: r

I am trying to match the '+' symbol inside my string using the pmatch function.

> Target = "18+"
>
> pmatch("+",Target)
>
> [1] NA

I observe similar behavior if I use match or grepl also.
If I try and use gsub, I get the following output.

> gsub("+","~",Target)
>
> [1] "~1~8~+~"

Can someone please explain me the reason for this behavior and a viable solution for my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a forward looking match. So it tries to match `"+"` to the first character of all elements in `table` (the second argument of `pmatch`). This fails (`"+" != "1"` ) so `NA` is returned. You must also be careful of the return value of `pmatch`. I'm going to quote from the help because it explains it succinctly and better than I ever could...

> *Exact matches are preferred to partial matches* (those where the value to be matched has an exact match to the initial part of the target, but the target is longer).
>
> If there is a single exact match or no exact match and a unique
>   partial match then the index of the matching value is returned; if
>   multiple exact or multiple partial matches are found then 0 is
>   returned and if no match is found then nomatch is returned.

```
###Examples from ?pmatch###
#  Multiple partial matches found - returns 0
charmatch("m",   c("mean", "median", "mode")) # returns 0

#  One exact match found - return index of match in table
charmatch("med", c("mean", "median", "mode")) # returns 2

#  One exact match found and preferred over partial match - index of exact match returned
charmatch("med", c("med", "median", "mode")) # returns 1
```

To get a vector of matches to `"+"` in your string I'd use `grepl`...

```
Target <- c( "+" , "+18" , "18+" , "23+26" , "1234" )
grepl( "\\+" , Target )
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`gsub("+","~",fixed=TRUE,Target)`

`?gsub`

> **fixed** - logical. If TRUE, pattern is a string to be matched as is.
>   Overrides all conflicting arguments.

Comment: may be also mention that you can escape `+` ie `gsub("\\+","~",Target)` since `+` means something in regex

Comment: Ok, through this I can replace the '+' symbol with the '~' character . But I still can't get it to work with either match, pmatch or grepl if I use the ~ symbol as my match pattern.
I would really like to know why this is happening. But for the time being I can move ahead with my work, I will replace the '+' symbol with a string and match it. 
I know this is not the best way to write the code, if someone can explain why I am unable to match special characters in a string. That would be great.
Thanks :)

Comment: @MayankBansal I don't know anything about `pmatch` but `gsub` and `grepl` use regex and in regex `+` is a special character which means match 1 or more. To escape `+` and have it find the literal `+` you add `\\ ` before it.

Comment: @JakeBurkhead but `fixed = TRUE` means do not treat the pattern as a regexp.

Comment: @Jake - using it \\ operator in grepl worked. Thanks
pmatch and match behave differently, I have no clue why

Comment: @SimonO101 I still think a complete answer would go over why `fixed = TRUE` is needed and how to do it without

Comment: @JakeBurkhead it seems to be in the answer? Sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The function `pmatch()` attempts to match the beginning elements, not the middle portions of elements.  So, the issue there has nothing to do with the plus symbol, `+`.  So, for example, the first two executions of `pmatch()` give `NA` as the result, the next three give `1` as the result (indicating a match of the beginning of the first element).

```
Target <- "18+"
pmatch("8", Target)
pmatch("+", Target)
pmatch("1", Target)
pmatch("18", Target)
pmatch("18+", Target)
```

The function `gsub()` can be used to match and replace portions of elements using regular expressions.  The plus sign has special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to use escape characters to indicate that you are interested in the plus sign as a single character.  For example, the following three lines of code give `"1~+"`, `"18~"`, and `"~"` as the results, respectively.

```
gsub("8", "~", Target)
gsub("\\+", "~", Target)
gsub("18\\+", "~", Target)
```

Comment: -1 *The function pmatch() attempts to match elements, not portions of elements*. This is clearly incorrect. `pmatch("1", "18+")`.

Comment: Right you are, @SimonO101.  I edited my post to try and clarify and to incorporate your example.  Thanks.